# Stoplight prism returning null when referencing a .json file in .yaml using $ref

Tags: prism, stoplight

I have a .yaml file, `api_spec.yaml`, and it's up and running. Inside, there's one endpoint (`paths:`) where I'm trying to refer to the entire `request_payload.json` file, stored in the same directory as `api_spec.yaml`.

```
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get a list of users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: 'request_payload.json'
```

However, when I tries to retrieve the object by using `http GET http://127.0.0.1:4010/users`, it's giving a 200 OK status, but the response body looks like

```
[
    null
]
```

How can I retrieve the entire object? I will attach my `request_payload.json` down as well:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jame Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using both `curl` and `http` command to run, and it's producing the same result.